# I cannot use pyautogui or pydirectinput for game scripting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a script for stardew valley, the mouse moves correctly and all the other stuff too, but when i use the click function it doesn't work

My code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
from PIL import ImageOps
import pydirectinput
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time
from numpy import *

test1 = (1400, 720)
test2 = (890, 420)
store = (1150, 420)


time.sleep(1.5)


def main():

    # pyautogui.write("t")
    # pyautogui.write("/emote angry")
    # pyautogui.press("enter")

    pyautogui.moveTo(store)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.rightClick()
    pydirectinput.rightClick()
    
main()
```

i've tried with both modules but none of them worked for me, and i have tried with other games and the click works

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old, but for those who'll reach here from search I'm answering this.

---

## TL;DR

No *pydirectinput*, no elevated privileges.

Just use *Both* `mouseDown` & `mouseUp`.

Sample code performing repetitive clicks that works in Stardew Valley:

```py
import pyautogui
import time


print("Starts in ", end="", flush=True)

for n in range(5, 0, -1):
    print(n, end=" ", flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)

print("\nStart", flush=True)

while True:
    pyautogui.mouseDown()
    pyautogui.mouseUp()
    time.sleep(2)
```

This will wait 5 seconds, then start pressing mouse every 2 secs.

One could use this for Slot machine in casino!

---

## What is Mouse Event

Despite `click()` and `mouseDown() / mouseUp()` seems same, under the hood they aren't.

In fact, mouse action isn't just as simple as we see.

Windows OS's, Microsoft's [Win32 API Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event) has quite specific Mouse Events:

```
MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE    (0x8000)
MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN    (0x0002)
MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP      (0x0004)
MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN  (0x0020)
MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP    (0x0040)
MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE        (0x0001)
MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN   (0x0008)
MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP     (0x0010)
MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL       (0x0800)
MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN       (0x0080)
MOUSEEVENTF_XUP         (0x0100)
MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL       (0x0800)
MOUSEEVENTF_HWHEEL      (0x01000)
```

These events are what's actually 'seen' by programs, and single event can have multiple of those.

If I understand correctly - This is simply done by adding, those events(or OR) as these are just flags with fancy name on it.

For i.e. if you want to press left click but release immediately, you could set a single mouse event's state to be `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN` + `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP` resulting flag 0x0006.

And that's what made `pyautogui.click()` don't work in stardew valley, while explicit up & down works.

---

## Peeking inside PyAutoGUI

To investigate further, we need to read PyAutGUI's [source code](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/b4255d0be42c377154c7d92337d7f8515fc63234/pyautogui/_pyautogui_win.py#L35).

If we see how `click` is implemented:

```py
def _click(x, y, button):
    ...

    if button == LEFT:
        EV = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTCLICK
    elif button == MIDDLE:
        EV = MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLECLICK
    elif button ==RIGHT:
        EV = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTCLICK

    try:
        _sendMouseEvent(EV, x, y)
    except (PermissionError, OSError):
        ...
```

We can see it's sending Mouse Events, but we never seen ones with *CLICK* in Microsoft's docs we saw earlier. So let's see what these are!

```py
# Event codes to be passed to the mouse_event() win32 function.
# Documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273(v=vs.85).aspx
MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001
MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002
MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004
MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTCLICK = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN + MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP
MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008
MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010
MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTCLICK = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN + MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP
MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020
MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040
MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLECLICK = MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN + MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP
```

Aha, just like I explained earlier, it's adding both Down & Up events to send both as single event!

From this - we can learn that:

1. `pyautogui.click()` is single mouse event.
2. `pyautogui.mouseDown()` & `pyautogui.mouseUp()` combos is two independent mouse event.
3. Therefore, `pyautogui.click()` is not same as `pyautogui.mouseDown()` & `pyautogui.mouseUp()`.

Since we know that Stardew Valley ignores `pyautogui.click()` we can assume that it only expects singular & independent input actions, not combined ones.

---

## Why only Stardew Valley?

This is what input *Godot Game Engine* sees during mouse click:

```js
...
InputEventMouseMotion: button_mask=0, position=((157, 365)), relative=((0, 0)), velocity=((-3.637545, 0)), pressure=0.00, tilt=((0, 0)), pen_inverted=(false)
InputEventMouseButton: button_index=1, mods=none, pressed=true, canceled=false, position=((157, 365)), button_mask=1, double_click=false
InputEventMouseButton: button_index=1, mods=none, pressed=false, canceled=false, position=((157, 365)), button_mask=0, double_click=false
...
```

Such events are what's given to game devs, and It's totally their freedom of how to utilize events to actually do something in-game.

So, we might never know! Maybe it was due to optimization, simply an oversight , or intended stuff!